# Generate a random number and another random number with certain margins from the first number

Tags: ruby, random

I start with `rand(1..117)`. Let's say it prints 80. I want to generate another random number between 20 less and 20 more than the first number, but still between 1 and 117, i.e., prevent negative numbers or numbers higher than 117.

I could get for example 50, 35, 55, 45, 64, 79, 99, 88, 108, etc. Each number is between 1 and 117, but no lower or higher than 20 from the number before it.

Comment: @chris: It's better to post a few lines of code, even if they're not working. It shows that you tried something and it gives us a starting point.

Comment: @chris  [at the moment stackoverflow isn't very welcoming](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/). This is the result of the rules, not so much the people, who are mostly truly helpful. It's changing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put both the random value-20 and the minimum (1) in an array and determine the maximum. Likewise with the value+20 and 117, but there you want the minimum.

This sounds way more complicated than it is:

```
puts r = rand(1..117)
99.times do
  puts r = rand([r-20, 1].max..[r+20, 117].min)
end
```

Comment: This answer is perfect. If not, add more on how this answer outputs different results than your explanation.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh It worked, I was used to IRB returning my desired output without having to press enter again, so I didn't haha. I did this time and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution:

```
def randwalk(min, max, step)
  return enum_for(__callee__, min, max, step) unless block_given?

  yield n = rand(min..max)

  loop do
    # min=1 // n=3  // step=20 => subtract up to 2
    # min=1 // n=50 // step=20 => subtract up to 20
    from = [min - n, -step].max

    # max=100 // n=97 // step=30 => add up to 3
    # max=100 // n=50 // step=30 => add up to 30
    to = [max - n, step].min

    yield n += rand(from..to)
  end
end

randwalk(1, 117, 20).first(10) # => [90, 89, 103, 87, 106, 94, 96, 99, 97, 103]
```

`randwalk` returns a Ruby [enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html) that yields as many values from the defined random walk as you opt to take. It will go on forever if you let it and it won't "step" outside of the given min/max. Let me know if you have any questions about the implementation or how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`clamp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Comparable.html#method-i-clamp) to ensure that a number is within a given range:

```
105.clamp(1, 117) #=> 105
120.clamp(1, 117) #=> 117
-15.clamp(1, 117) #=> 1
```

To generate a random sequence where each number is within ±20 of the previous one (and still within 1..117), I'd use an [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html):

```
random_sequence = Enumerator.new do |y|
  min = 1
  max = 117
  num = rand(min..max)
  loop do
    y << num
    num = rand((num - 20).clamp(min, max)..(num + 20).clamp(min, max))
  end
end

random_sequence.take(10)
#=> [12, 31, 50, 47, 57, 73, 66, 46, 60, 46]
```

Comment: Or just `num = (num + rand(-20..20)).clamp(min, max)`.

Comment: @mwp clamping afterwards gives more weight to the limits.